# Different users on a machine have different versions of numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have installed numpy on my debian machine using pip. Additionally, I think an older version of numpy is installed through `apt-get`.

Different users on my machine see the same numpy file, but have different versions of the software. For example, when I run `python -c 'import os,numpy;print(numpy.__file__); print(numpy.version.version)'`, both users print `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc`, but one of them has version 1.12.1 and the other has 1.14.

I tried to remove numpy version that is installed through apt-get, but it will remove some other software as well. So I am hoping to find a solution that avoids removing the version installed through apt-get.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue before?

Answer (score 1):

you must have installed numpy manually using setup.py and apt pkg as well
you could do:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
sys.path.remove('/usr/lib/python/path/2/numpy')

in your app/__init__.py
```

set PYTHONHOME to your preference.  you could also use virtualenv to keep multiple python environments and switch between them.